# How to programmatically check the "No Thumbnail" check box when posting a link

Tags: asp.net, json, facebook-graph-api

Our application allows our users to post messages to Facebook.  If a users wants to post a link such as http://yahoo.com in a message, an image appears with the link in the post.

When posting a message with a link directly on Facebook, it give you the option to check the "No Thumbnail" box so that the image is not shown.  How can I do this programmatically using the `graph.facebook.api`?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to post link from your site, then just don't pass other parameters and just pass `message` field with your link and it'll post only the link without any other fields.

But if you want to post as full message but no thumbnail, then don't pass `picture` param.

It would be better if you could share your code so we can suggest you the right solution, if the above doesn't help you.

Comment: I actually tried not passing the picture param, but it still posts an image in the post:  I'm sending the urls shortly

Comment: This is the url our process send for no thumbnail: https://graph.facebook.com/100000605881875/feed?access_token=XXXX&message=testing%20link%20http%3A%2F%2Fyahoo.com&link=http://yahoo.com&name=Yahoo!&caption=http://yahoo.com&description=Welcome to Yahoo!, the world's most visited home page. Quickly find what you're searching for, get in touch with friends and stay in-the-know with the latest news and information.

Comment: Whether or not I have the picture param in the url, it still show an image as shown in the previous screencast link.  Let me know.

Comment: Okay, I did few tests and it seems like you cannot remove the thumbnail, however you can attach 1x1 size image to `picture` key and when you see the post, it'll look like it doesn't have any thumbnail, but it'll leave a blank space and won't look like the normal share you do through fb system with no thumbnail option checked. Try with this link as picture just for testing purpose: `http://placehold.it/1x1`

Comment: No problem, Let me know if you need any help :)

Comment: Tried your suggestion, but I see what you mean about the blank box. http://screencast.com/t/qEAJqCqsRh.  Probably not acceptable for our purposes, but it you find out a better solution, please post it here.  Thanks again!

Comment: Sure, If i find any other solution, I'll definitely post it here!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take a look at this https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/190261237768904 . 
It was a bug that has now been fixed. It points to an approach where you specify a picture parameter but leave its value empty.